# Using TextBox to insert formula

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, textbox

I’m hoping someone could help me with this coding.

```
ActiveCell.Formula = “=“”&IF TextBox3.Value = 1 Then “Z_End” Else “Z_Origin””
```

I want the active cells formula to look something like `=Z_End` or `=Z_Origin`.

Comment: Please explain your problem further - is there anything not working with the given code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `IIf`:

```
 ActiveCell.Formula = IIf(TextBox3.Value = 1, "=Z_End", "=Z_Origin")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TextBox3_Change()
    MsgBox TextBox3.Value
    If TextBox3.Value = 1 Then
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Z_End"
    Else
        ActiveCell.Formula = "=Z_Origin"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: might be should be If TextBox3.Value = "1" Then